# Azure Cloud Service Endpoint for VM to only allow internal access

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a VM running SQL Server. I have port 1433 open on the Windows firewall and an Endpoint on the corresponding cloud service forwarding port 57501 to 1433. I haven't specified any ACLs on that endpoint. I want the endpoint to only be accessible from a specific subnet in the VNet where the VM exists.

If I set that in the ACL, it doesn't work - the ACL only seems to care about the public IP of the client. Since the public IP may change, this isn't an option.

What's the recommended approach here? Note that I don't want to connect directly to the VM hostname because I want to use the CNAME that the cloud service sets up for me (the actual Windows computer name is a random long string).

Comment: I would suggest to setup NSGs (Network Security Groups)

Comment: So network security groups will pair okay with cloud service end points even though the endpoint URL is a pubic ip?

Answer (score 0):

[NSGs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/) apply rules on the incoming/outgoing traffic at a VM or cloud-service-role-instance level.

**Note** that NSGs default rules allow traffic within the virtual network, and outbound to Internet. All other traffic is denied by default. You need to explicitly specify rules to change this behavior or allow any other traffic in/out.

You can create an NSG rule like below to allow only traffic from a specific subnet within a VNet.

```
Get-AzureNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "NSG-FrontEnd" `
| Set-AzureNetworkSecurityRule -Name rdp-rule `
    -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -Type Inbound -Priority 100 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix 192.168.1.0/24  -SourcePortRange '*' `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix '*' -DestinationPortRange '1433'
```

Comment: right...but when the traffic comes through a cloud service endpoint, the SourceDestinationPrefix is the cloud service endpoint IP, not the internet VNet subnet...right?

Comment: Yes, I missed the point that you were trying to use the CNAME of the cloud service to access the SQL server. This way you are going through the Internet routable IP address. This contradicts with your requirement for the SQL server to be accessible from a specific subnet.

Instead, you can setup the SQL server with a static VNET ip address, setup NSG rules to allow access to a subnet, and use the static IP address to connect from within that subnet.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-private-ip/.